# Composite key being saved as null

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, composite-key

I am trying to persist a Template object in the app's database. It's not giving me any exceptions but I get the default message from Grails for trying to save an object with a null attribute when the same is marked with nullable:false constraint.

> Property tempVersion of class Template cannot be null or (default.null.message)

The Template class is the following:

```
class Template implements Serializable {

Long tempVersion
String name
Type type
Status status
App app
String body
Tester tester
Date date


static constraints = {
    name blank:false, maxSize:50
    type nullable:false
    status nullable:false
    app nullable:false 
    body blank:false, widget:"textarea"
}

static mapping = {
    id composite:['id','tempVersion']
    tempVersion generator:"sequence", params:[sequence:'SEQ_TEMPLATE_VERSION']
    body type:"text"
    version false
}
```

I cannot understand why is that, cause if I specify tempVersion as a primary key along with the default 'id', it should never generate a null value! Just as shouldn't generate a null id. 
Anyway, does anybody see what I am doing wrong about that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write custom sequence generator if you want generate value foe composite ID. 
Hibernate doesn't generate values for composite IDs